# Mac OS X: Maximum installer size?

Tags: macos, installation, package, filesize

I just like to ask if it is documented re. the maximum size of an installer in Mac?
I am trying to create a Mac installer using Packages, and I am just curious if there is a maximum file size that I can add on the installer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the limit for the installer as a whole (as a PKG file), then the answer can be found here: [Mac OS X File Size Limits](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2422?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)
For Mac OS X 10.5.3 and later, the limit is: **close to 8 EB**.

If you want the limit for a file that will be included as a payload of the installer, then the answer can be found here: [CPIO](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cpio.1.html)

For flat packages, installer payloads are gzipped cpio archives, so the maximum file size you can add to it is **8GB**. Note that this limitation applies to a per file basis.
For example, you can add a total of 100 GB as the payload, provided that each file (file1, file2, file3, and so on..) does not exceed the 8 GB limitation.